# Looking for meat ingredient suggestions for a Yoghurt Cake recipe

Tags: meat, cake, ingredient-selection

I know the flavours of "meat" and "sweet" can sometimes go together well. There's a sausage and fennel (licorice sensation) pastry that I very much enjoy. That's the concept this question is based in.

We're having an office bake-off based on Yoghurt Cake.  I'd like to do something different and use meat in the cake instead of fruit, seeds, nuts or assorted sweets.  However I can't find any recipes online that include meat.  I know bacon is often all the rage so that interests me but I'm open to any kind of meat.

I'm not a cook and am looking for some seasoned advice about what meats to use in a standard Yoghurt cake recipe, and the best way to prepare the meat for it.  This is one example of a standard Yoghurt Cake recipe from which I would base my own concoction - http://happyhomebaking.blogspot.ca/2007/09/another-yogurt-cake.html

Comment: I think the words "standard" and "meat yoghurt cake recipe" are a contradiction in terms...

Answer (score 2):

Bacon works well in sweet dishes because it is quite sweet itself. Why not try a sweet-cured bacon in a subtly maple-flavoured cake?

You can really boost the sweetness of the bacon by putting it in a very low oven for long time. It pretty much crystallises.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a batch of sweet and cinnamon-y candied bacon and then chop it into pieces to mix into the cake batter?  Sprinkle some on top of the frosting to deliver the sweet bacon flavor with each bite.

Here's the "Recipe Girl's" candied bacon recipe with step-by-step color pictures....yum!

http://www.recipegirl.com/2012/04/13/candied-bacon/

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion of bacon already put out there I will suggest another meat that goes well with yogurt and works well WITH sweet, but is not itself sweet, Lamb.